# Display the current loading resource in Firefox

Tags: firefox

My Firefox sometimes displays a "transferring data from ..." message indefinitely, seems like it is trying to load a resource forever.

[image: hangs]

However I want to know what exactly was requested, for example the path.

From Firebug I see one request to the same domain:

[image: firebug]

However it says it is completed, with a 200 status, so I am not sure if this is the same request which hangs.

### Update

When I disabled all addons, and used the build-in developer tool, I get this:

[image: buildin dev tool]

As you can see, it is still transfering data, but all the requests shown are done.

Comment: Are you able to isolate the individual calls to the `api` URL? Or possibly run something like WireShark to capture if there is actually traffic when it says it is transferring?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool built-in to Firefox called the Developer Console. You can access it by pressing `F12` or rightclicking on the page and selecting `Inspect Element`.

On there is a tab called Network, if you click on that you can see all the resources a page has requested. You may need to refresh the page to get it to populate. I've attached a screenshot of results from this question before I answered it.

[image: Screenshot of the Firefox developer console showing the Network tab]

Comment: I am afraid this is the same as Firebug, the requests I see are 200.